# Proving $6n^4>(n+2)^4$ for $n\geq 4$, by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction

> I need to prove that:
> $$6n^4>(n+2)^4$$
> for $n\geq4$ is true using proof by induction.

I've started by showing that when $P(4)$ is true since $\text{LHS}=1536$ and $\text{RHS}=1296$.

I then let $k≥4$ and assumed $P(k)$ is true, which is $6k^4>(k+2)^4$.

So we need to show that P(k+1) is true, so,
$$6(k+1)^4>(k+3)^4$$

This is where I get stuck, so would be very grateful if anybody could help finish the proof.

Thanks
Kara :-)

Comment: You have the setup correct, so that is a good start. What have you tried? My first instinct would be to expand out both $6(k + 1)^4$ and $(k + 3)^4$ and see if you can rewrite the inequality in an equivalent form that allows you to directly compare it to the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}4]{6}(k+1)=\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}4]{6}k+\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}4]{6}>(k+2)+1=k+3$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your induction step of $P(k)$, you want to somehow "change" the inequality so or one side or the other becomes that of $P(k+1)$ while also showing the inequality still holds. With the left side, to get from $6k^4$ to $6(k+1)^4$, since it's multiplicative, one way to do this is to divide by $k^4$ and then multiply by $(k+1)^4$, i.e., multiply both sides by $\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^4$. Doing this gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
6k^4 & \gt (k + 2)^4 \\
6k^4\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^4 & \gt (k + 2)^4\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^4 \\
6(k+1)^4 & \gt \left(\frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{k}\right)^4 \\
& = \left(\frac{k^2 + 3k + 2}{k}\right)^4 \\
& = \left(k + 3 + \frac{2}{k}\right)^4 \\
& \gt (k + 3)^4
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This proves $P(k + 1)$ is true.